# Building Drop Down Options from Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

I have a landing page I'm working on, where I want the user to select a state, and then when the state is selected, the select dropdown below it will show the locations within that state. The list of locations comes from a json file where there is a list of store locations, with their attributes such as store name, state, etc. I've created an object, but I'm not sure how to populate the select based on the state. Also, the way I'm building the list of states may not be the best way either, so any help there would be great also. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var buildLocations = {

    'settings': {
        directoryListingItems   :   {},
        directoryListingArray   :   [],
        globalLatLong           :   null,
        globalLatitude          :   geoip_latitude(),
        globalLongitude         :   geoip_longitude(),
        globalCity              :   geoip_city(),
        globalState             :   geoip_region_name(),
        locationRadius          :   30,
        NearbyLocationsCount    :   0,
        locationTotalPlaceholder:   $('#location-number'),
        locationNamePlaceholder :   $('#location-name'),
        stateDropdownArray      :   [],
        stateDropdown           :   $('#state'),
        locationDropdownArray   :   [],
        locationDropdown        :   $('#location'),
    },

    init: function() {
        bLs = this.settings;
        buildLocations.getJSONLocations();
    },

    getJSONLocations: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data/data.json",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: buildLocations.getLocations
        });
    },

    getLocations: function(results) {


        // creating objects
        for(var i = 0; i < results.locations.length; i++) {

        bLs.directoryListingItems = {
        store_id: results.locations[i].storeid,
            title: results.locations[i].title,
            latitude: results.locations[i].latitude,
            longitude: results.locations[i].longitude,
        state: results.locations[i].state,
        distance: buildLocations.getLocationDistance(bLs.globalLatitude, bLs.globalLongitude, results.locations[i].latitude, results.locations[i].longitude)
        };
        bLs.directoryListingArray.push(bLs.directoryListingItems);

        //Check if a state is already in the states array, if not, add it
        if ($.inArray('<option value=\"' + bLs.directoryListingArray[i].state + '\">'+ bLs.directoryListingArray[i].state + '</option>', bLs.stateDropdownArray)==-1) {
                bLs.stateDropdownArray.push('<option value=\"' + bLs.directoryListingArray[i].state + '\">'+ bLs.directoryListingArray[i].state + '</option>');
                //alert("added"+ value.state);
        }

        //get selected state value
        //if in state in bLs.directoryListingItems array matches this value, add item to array

        //Add Each location to the locations dropdown
        bLs.locationDropdownArray.push('<option value=\"' + bLs.directoryListingArray[i].storeid + '\">'+ bLs.directoryListingArray[i].title + '</option>');

        //Count the number of locations that are within the set location radius of the users detected location
        if (bLs.directoryListingArray[i].distance < bLs.locationRadius) {
            bLs.NearbyLocationsCount++;
        }

        }
        //Sort the states array in alphabetical order
        bLs.stateDropdownArray.sort();

        //run function to populate dropdowns
        buildLocations.populateDOM();
    },

    compareDistances: function(a,b) {
        if (a.distance < b.distance)
            return -1;
        if (a.distance > b.distance)
            return 1;
            return 0;
    },  

    populateDOM: function() {

        //populate the number inside the map marker
        bLs.locationTotalPlaceholder.text(bLs.NearbyLocationsCount);
        //populate the area next to the map marker with the users location and state            
        bLs.locationNamePlaceholder.text(bLs.globalCity + ", " + bLs.globalState);          

        //build state select dropdown
        bLs.stateDropdown.html(bLs.stateDropdownArray);

        buildLocations.populateDOMlocations();
    },

    populateDOMlocations: function() {

        //$.each(bLs.directoryListingItems, function(index, value) {
            //if (value.state="Florida") {
                //alert(index)
            ///}

        //});

        //$.each(bLs.directoryListingItems, function(index, obj) {
            //$.each(obj, function(attr, value) {
            //  console.log( attr + ' == ' + value );
            //});
        //});   

        //build locations select dropdown
        bLs.locationDropdown.html(bLs.locationDropdownArray);

    },

    getLocationDistance : function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
            function deg2rad(deg) {
                return deg * (Math.PI/180)
            };

            var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
            var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
            var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
            var a = 
            Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
            ; 
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            var d = (R * c) * 0.6214; // Distance in miles
            return Math.round( d * 10 ) / 10
    },

};



// ====================================================== //
// Populate Locations

buildLocations.init();





});
```

Comment: Where is `bLs.locationDropdown` defined?

Comment: it's defined in the init function, but it's in settings. I actually figured it out though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

```
    populateDOMlocations: function() {

        bLs.currState = bLs.stateDropdown.val();
        bLs.locationDropdownArray = [];

        for(var l = 0; l < bLs.directoryListingArray.length; l++) {
            if (bLs.directoryListingArray[l].state == bLs.currState ) {
                bLs.locationDropdownArray.push('<option value=\"' + bLs.directoryListingArray[l].storeid + '\">'+ bLs.directoryListingArray[l].title + '</option>');
            }
        }

        bLs.locationDropdownArray.sort();

        //build locations select dropdown
        bLs.locationDropdown.html(bLs.locationDropdownArray);

    },
```